# Add associate array values in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with the following properties:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [project] => test proposal
            [type] => pending
            [0] => 10,000
            [1] => 10,000
            [2] => 5,000
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [project] => test 3
            [type] => won
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 20,000
            [3] => 20,000
            [4] => 10,000
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [project] => Test 3
            [type] => pending
            [0] => 8,333
            [1] => 8,333
            [2] => 8,333
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
        )

)
```

I'd like to push a last item to the array that combines the values of all of the others, project and type can be blank. So the outcome would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [project] => test proposal
            [type] => pending
            [0] => 10,000
            [1] => 10,000
            [2] => 5,000
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [project] => test 3
            [type] => won
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 20,000
            [3] => 20,000
            [4] => 10,000
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [project] => Test 3
            [type] => pending
            [0] => 8,333
            [1] => 8,333
            [2] => 8,333
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
        )

     [3] => Array
        (
            [project] => 
            [type] => 
            [0] => 18,333
            [1] => 18,333
            [2] => 33,333
            [3] => 20,000
            [4] => 10,000
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        if($v== 'project' || $v == 'type') continue;
        $newArr[$k] = $newArr[$k] + $v;
    }
}
$array[] = $newArr;
```

Comment: you need to append `newArr` to `$array`.. isnt it?

Comment: @Stoic our answers look remarkable similar. :) Which do you think would be faster, the `if($v =='project') continue;` that I've got, or the `if(is_numeric($key))` that you've got? I think my code would beat yours by a thrilling .005ms !!Bwa ha ha

Comment: well, I would love to keep my code concise.. :P he can keep the one which looks nicer to him.. but though, to be honest.. for a real correct answer, we need to add `$sum=array('project'=>'','type'=>'');` at the very top ;) which we both forgot :P and FatherStorm kept.

Answer (score 2):

like this perhaps?:

```
$temp=array('project'=>'','type'=>'');
foreach($array as $project=> $data){
    foreach($data as $node=>$value){
        if(is_int($node) && is_int($value)){
            @$temp[$node]+=$value;
        }
    }
}
$array[]=$temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as $sub) {
    foreach ($sub as $key => $value) {
        if (is_numeric($key)) $sum[$key] += $value;
    }
}
$data[] = $sum;
```